# On an infinite dimensional locally convex space, no weakly-continuous semi-norm is a norm

Tags: topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces, weak-topology

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional locally convex space that separates points and $X^*$ its dual. I would like to prove that no $\sigma(X, X^*)$-continuous semi-norm is actually a norm.

What I have done so far: Let $U$ be any neighborhood of $0$ in the weak topology. Since the weak topology is not locally bounded, it is known that $U$ contains an infinite dimensional subspace. Thus by the Kolmogorov normability criterion, the space $X$ is not normable.

I have two questions:

1. Is the use of the Kolmogorov normability criterion justified here? It requires us to show that $0$ has no bounded convex neighborhood of the origin. However, in my approach I am using only a subset of all possible seminorms (only those which are weakly continuous).
2. I have shown that $X$ is not normable. But I think this is incomplete, as it does not rule out one particular seminorm being a norm which is what I want to show. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\rho$ be a weakly-continuous seminorm.  This implies there exists some $\delta>0$ and $\Lambda_1,\dots\Lambda_n\in X^*$ such that for all $x\in X$
$$\left(\forall i\in\{1,\dots,n\}:|\Lambda_i(x)| < \delta\right) \implies \rho(x)< 1\quad (1)$$
Let $A:X\to\Bbb{F}^n$ be the map
$$A(x)=\left(\Lambda_1(x),\dots,\Lambda_n(x)\right)^\top$$
Since $A$ is a linear map from an infinite-dimensional space to a finite-dimensional space, it cannot be injective.  Therefore, there exists some $v\in X$, $v\ne 0$ such that $A(v)=0$.  This means $\Lambda_1(v)=\dots=\Lambda_n(v)=0$.

So for any $a\in \Bbb{F}, a>0$, $\Lambda_1(av)=\dots=\Lambda_n(av)=0$ and therefore from $(1)$ it follows that $a\rho(v)=|a|\rho(v)=\rho(av) < 1$.  Since $a$ is an arbitrary positive number, this can only be if $\rho(v)=0$.  Hence $\rho$ is not a norm.

Comment: Thank you, can you explain where the condition (1) comes from? I know it has to do with weak continuity, but I am having trouble seeing how exactly it is a consequence of it.

Comment: weakly-continuous $\implies \rho^{-1}(U)$ is weakly-open for any open set $U\subseteq \Bbb{F}$.  So take $U=(-1,1)$.   Then $\rho^{-1}(U)$ must contain a weak  open neighborhood of zero.  The left hand side is the most general form of a weak basic open neighborhood of zero (i.e. from the basis defining the weak topology.)

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. Does that mean the right hand side of (1) should be $|\rho(x)| < 1$?

Comment: @CBBAM:  $\rho$ maps into $\Bbb{R}_{\ge 0}$, so $\rho^{-1}$ of $[0,1)$, $(-1,1)$ or $\{z\in \Bbb{C}: |z| < 1\}$ are all the same.